# Are there functors $F,G:\textbf{Set}^{\operatorname{op}}\to\textbf{Set}$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}(F,G)$ is NOT a set?

Tags: category-theory

Are there functors $F,G:\textbf{Set}^{\operatorname{op}}\to\textbf{Set}$ such that the collection $\operatorname{Hom}(F,G)$ is **not** a set?

Same question for $F,G:\textbf{Set}\to\textbf{Set}$.

[$\textbf{Set}$ is the category of sets, $\textbf{Set}^{\operatorname{op}}$ is the opposite category, and $\operatorname{Hom}(F,G)$ is the collection of all morphisms from $F$ to $G$.]

[Related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/309222/461)

Comment: What's a morphism between two functors?

Comment: See [Natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) (Wikipedia entry). @AsafKaragila

Comment: Ugh. I hate that term. It evokes a mental block.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If that makes difference for you, it is the equalizer of$$\prod_XGX^{FX}\rightrightarrows\prod_{Y,Z}(GZ^{FY})^{Z^Y}$$:)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: You mean Denzel Washington or Edward Woodward?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე you should specify that the parallel maps are $(\alpha_X) \mapsto (f \mapsto \alpha_Z \circ F(f))_{Y, Z}$ and $(\alpha_X) \mapsto (f \mapsto G(f) \circ \alpha_Y)_{Y, Z}$ -- you know, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I don't think Asaf will appreciate that :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By [a theorem of Freyd and Street](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/1-09abs.html), a category $\mathcal{C}$ is esentially small if and only if both $\mathcal{C}$ and the presheaf category of $\mathcal{C}$ are locally small. Since $\mathbf{Set}$ is not essentially small, its presheaf category cannot be locally small, hence the $F$ and $G$ that you desire must exist.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll look at the paper. [Link to the pdf file](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/v1n9.pdf). It would be interesting to know if there are explicit examples.

Comment: I forgot to welcome you to MSE!!!

Comment: Thanks, Pierre-Yves!

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Freyd constructs an explicit example, no?

Comment: @KevinCarlson yes: take the functor $A\to Set$ sending an object $a$ to the set that is the disjoint union of a one-element set with the set of isomorphism classes of monics $b\hookrightarrow a$ for which there exists a retract $a\to b$. There is an explicit injective function from the collection of isomorphism classes of $A$ to the endomorphisms of this functor. For $A=Set^{op}$, this amounts to sending a set $X$ to the set of isomorphism classes of quotients of $X$ that admit a section (ie all of them if AC holds), disjoint union one more element.

Comment: So in the presence of AC, take $G=F$, both being $a \mapsto EqRel(a) \amalg \{0\}$ on objects, where $EqRel(a)$ is the set of equivalence relations on $a$. On functions $f\colon b\to a$, pull back the equivalence relation along $f$, and take the identity on $\{0\}$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - About your phrase: "pull back the equivalence relation along $f$". It seems to me what we should do instead is pull back the equivalence relation along $f$ *if* for all $x\in a$ there is a $y\in b$ such that $f(y)$ is equivalent to $x$, *and* send the equivalence relation to $0$ otherwise. (See the definition of $Tf$ p. 175 of the Freyd-Street paper.)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard ah, yes, I didn't check the definition of the functor on morphisms, and just guessed it! My apologies.

Comment: @SofieVerbeek - Hi Sofie! I've just posted a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2906175/660