# Is the collection of all subfunctors of a given representable endofunctor of $\textbf{Set}$ a set?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F$ be a representable endofunctor of the category **Set** of sets.

(1) Is the collection of all subfunctors of $F$ a set?

(2) Same question with "representable endofunctor of **Set**" replaced by "representable functor from $\mathcal C$ to **Set**, where $\mathcal C$ is a locally small category".

(3) Same question with "subfunctors" replaced by "quotients".

[Of course, (2) is a generalization of (1).]

**Edit.** If we drop the representability assumption, we can find examples where the collections of subfunctors and of quotients are *not* sets. Indeed, in the notation of

Peter Freyd, Ross Street, On the size of categories, TAC 1 (1995) pp.174-185 http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/1995/n9/v1n9.pdf

let $\mathcal A$ be the category of sets, and, for each set $K$, let $U_K$ be the image of the endomorphism $\theta K$ of $T$. Then $U_K$ is a quotient and a subfunctor of $T$, and $U_K\neq U_L$ for $K$ and $L$ of different cardinalities. (Clearly $T$ is *not* representable.)

Comment: Have you tried finding examples of subfunctors? Look at the endofunctor $\operatorname{Hom}(\{x\},\,\cdot\,)$ for instance. Take a non-trivial subfunctor $F$. For some set $S$, the set $F(S)$ does not contain a fixed element $s$ of $S$. For any other set $S'$, we can consider the morphism $S' \to S$ sending every element of $S'$ to $s$. The resulting morphism $F(S') \to F(S)$ won't exist unless $F(S')$ is empty, but in that case consider any morphism $S \to S'$ and you'll run into a contradiction.

Comment: @SofieVerbeek - Thanks! Yes I looked at your example (which is the identity functor (up to isomorphism)). In this case I agree with you that there are only two subfunctors: the functor itself and the initial object of our category of functors. In all the examples I've been able to check, the subfunctors (and the quotients) form a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), note that if $G$ is a subfunctor of $\text{Hom}(X,-)$ and if $\alpha\in G(Y)$ for some set $Y$, and $\beta:X\to Z$ induces the same equivalence relation on $X$ as $\alpha$ does (i.e., if $\alpha(x)=\alpha(x')\Leftrightarrow\beta(x)=\beta(x')$ for $x,x'\in X$), then $\beta$ factors through $\alpha$, and so $\beta\in G(Z)$.

So $G$ is determined by the class of equivalence relations on $X$ induced by elements of $G(Y)$ for sets $Y$. But there is only a set of such classes.

For (2), take $\mathcal{C}$ to have objects $X$ and $\{Y_i\vert i\in I\}$ for some proper class $I$, with the only non-identity morphisms being a morphism $X\to Y_i$ for each $i$. Then $\text{Hom}(X,-)$ has a proper class of subfunctors, since $\text{Hom}(Y_i,-)$ is isomorphic to a subfunctor for every $i\in I$.

For (3), note that if $G$ is a quotient functor of $\text{Hom}(X,-)$, and $\alpha,\beta\in\text{Hom}(X,Y)$, then $\alpha=\beta$ in $G(Y)$ if and only if $\bar{\alpha}=\bar{\beta}$ in $G\left(\text{im}(\alpha)\cup\text{im}(\beta)\right)$, where $\bar{\alpha}$ and $\bar{\beta}$ are the functions obtained by restricting the codomain of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This is because if $r:Y\to\text{im}(\alpha)\cup\text{im}(\beta)$ is any retraction, then $r\circ\alpha=\bar{\alpha}$ and $r\circ\beta=\bar{\beta}$.

So $G$ is determined by the choice of a set of pairs of functions from $X$ to sets with cardinality at most twice that of $X$, and there is only a set of such choices up to isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer! (I think $\bar{\alpha}\circ r=\alpha$ should be $r\circ\alpha=\bar{\alpha}$, and similarly for $\beta$.)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Thanks, I’ve fixed that.